# Blog custom URL

Tags: nodes

Is it possible to have, for example, www.mydomain.com/blog/username instead of www.mydomain.com/blog/1, as blog URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just install the [Pathauto module](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto), visit `admin/config/search/path/patterns` and look at the bottom of the page for this pattern text field:

[image: Pathauto Blog Path]

You can use the standard path recommended by Pathauto (which I think is exactly what you're looking for) or use the Replacement Patterns to build up a more satisfactory URL.